# How to speed up the Keras model.predict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-science

I have trained a LSTM model and tried to make predictions for all test observations. However, it takes forever for keras `model.predict` to calculate all predictions. Is there a way to speed up this process? Assume there are two features (x1 & x2) for each prediction. The length of each feature (x1 & x2) are 33. Such as [32,1,17,.......,0]. I need to make 1M predictions. My code is

```
predictions = np.argmax(make.predict([x1, x2]), axis = -1)
```

Any idea to speed up? Many Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Actually, Keras model is a main architecture to perform, training, retraining, finetuning and summary and model wise changes, While doing predictions and deployment, we need to use `frozen inference graph of keras model`.

We should also gone for `Frozen graph optimization` with use of [TensorRT](https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt), [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Model_Optimization_Techniques.html) and many other Model Optimization techniques.

Here i have added snippet to convert graph from Keras model

Links to freeze graph

[Convert Keras Model to TensorFlow frozen graph](https://ksingh7.medium.com/part-iii-convert-keras-model-to-tensorflow-frozen-graph-model-a6aa6b1aaeee)

[Save, Load and Inference From TensorFlow 2.x Frozen Graph](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Save-Load-Inference-From-TF2-Frozen-Graph/)

It might looks lengthy, but its actual method

#Freeze Graph

```
# Convert Keras model to ConcreteFunction
full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype))

# Get frozen ConcreteFunction
frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)
frozen_func.graph.as_graph_def()


# Save frozen graph from frozen ConcreteFunction to hard drive
tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                  logdir="./frozen_models",
                  name="frozen_graph.pb",
                  as_text=False)
```

#Load Frozen Graph

```
   # Load frozen graph using TensorFlow 1.x functions
with tf.io.gfile.GFile("./frozen_models/frozen_graph.pb", "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    loaded = graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

# Wrap frozen graph to ConcreteFunctions
frozen_func = wrap_frozen_graph(graph_def=graph_def,
                                inputs=["x:0"],
                                outputs=["Identity:0"],
                                print_graph=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do the predictions in parallel, like 20-40 threads simultaneously using `multiprocessing`:

```
import multiprocessing

output=[]
data = range(0,len(x1.shape[0])) #length of x1 set, not the 33 columns

def f(x):

    predictions = np.argmax(model.predict([x1, x2]), axis = -1)  
    return predictions

def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(40) # number of parallel threads
    r=p.map(f, data)
    return r
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    output.append(mp_handler())
```

You will get all your predictions at `output[0]`